Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps при подключении Allure отчета
Начал ловить ошибку в некоторых тестах (Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps), при попытке сделать скрины для аллюр отчета
Аллюр подключаю таким образом:
kaspressoBuilder = Kaspresso.Builder.withForcedAllureSupport().addComposeSupport

Полная ошибка:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps
at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfHwBitmapInSwMode(BaseCanvas.java:706)
at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:81)
at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseCanvas.java:139)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1604)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidCanvas.drawImageRect-HPBpro0(AndroidCanvas.android.kt:271)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.CanvasDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(CanvasDrawScope.kt:263)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(Unknown Source:39)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs$default(DrawScope.kt:510)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.BitmapPainter.onDraw(BitmapPainter.kt:93)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter.draw-x_KDEd0(Painter.kt:212)
at coil.compose.AsyncImagePainter.onDraw(AsyncImagePainter.kt:210)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter.draw-x_KDEd0(Painter.kt:212)
at androidx.compose.ui.draw.PainterModifier.draw(PainterModifier.kt:281)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.draw(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:381)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:92)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:371)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:397)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:273)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:355)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:840)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:151)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:840)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:151)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:64)
at androidx.compose.material.ripple.AndroidRippleIndicationInstance.drawIndication(Ripple.android.kt:184)
at androidx.compose.foundation.IndicationModifier.draw(Indication.kt:183)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.draw(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:381)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:92)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.performDraw(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:74)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:54)
at androidx.compose.foundation.Background.draw(Background.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.draw(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:381)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:92)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:371)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:397)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:273)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:355)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:840)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:151)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:397)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:273)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:355)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:840)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:151)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:64)
at androidx.compose.foundation.DrawOverscrollModifier.draw(AndroidOverscroll.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.draw(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:381)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:92)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:371)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:397)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:273)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:355)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:397)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:273)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:355)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:840)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:151)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:64)
at androidx.compose.foundation.Background.draw(Background.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.draw(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:381)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:92)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:371)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:236)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:368)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:397)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:273)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:355)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:840)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:151)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt)


На эмуляторе тестируете?

Да, при чем есть два проекта, на одном все нормально, на другом вот эта ошибка, и там и там эмуляторы одинаковые

Посмотрите настройки эмулятора касательно графики. Ошибка как раз на это намекает. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328225/cant-change-emulated-performance-of-avd-in-android-studio

Пробовал ставить и Hardware и Software

Мое решение это поменять реализацию ScreenshotsImpl в сетапе:
kaspressoBuilder = Kaspresso.Builder.withForcedAllureSupport {
        libLogger = UiTestLoggerImpl(DEFAULT_LIB_LOGGER_TAG)
        resourceFileNamesProvider = DefaultResourceFileNamesProvider(addTimestamps = false)
        dirsProvider = DefaultDirsProvider(instrumentalDependencyProviderFactory.getComponentProvider<Kaspresso>(instrumentation))
        resourcesDirNameProvider = DefaultResourcesDirNameProvider()
        resourcesDirsProvider = DefaultResourcesDirsProvider(dirsProvider = dirsProvider, resourcesDirNameProvider = resourcesDirNameProvider)
        resourcesRootDirsProvider = DefaultResourcesRootDirsProvider()
        resourceFilesProvider = DefaultResourceFilesProvider(resourcesRootDirsProvider, resourcesDirsProvider, resourceFileNamesProvider)
        screenshots = ScreenshotsImpl(
            logger = libLogger,
            resourceFilesProvider = resourceFilesProvider,
            screenshotMaker = ExternalScreenshotMaker(
                instrumentalDependencyProviderFactory.getComponentProvider<ExternalScreenshotMaker>(
                    instrumentation
                ),
                ScreenshotParams(quality = 50)
            )
        )
    }

